# How to use PHP Tokens to make a login with electron

Tags: javascript, php, electron, token

So I've setup a local server on my pc (XAMP) I'm also running a local electron application, I have a html5 file on my electron app that takes in user input(username,password) and runs it against the database on my local server. I know what I'm doing doesn't work and shouldn't work - but I also know it's not completely hopeless, could anyone describe how I could use tokens to send back a GET response to verify the input username and password is present in the database?
Thanks for your help.

```
<?php
session_start();

require('../login/connect.php');

$username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
$password = stripcslashes($_POST['password']);


if ($username && $password){

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$password);

$query = "select * from `users` where username='".sha1($username)."'
and password='".sha1($password)."'";

$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($rows==1){
echo'This thing works';
    }else{

        echo'Not working';
    }
}else{

    header('Location: ../index.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Why are you `sha1()`ing $username?

Also, don't use `mysqli_real_escape_string`, simply bind the variables to your query.

Comment: My register system works with sha1, everything apart from ids are encrypted in sha1.

Comment: A "token" can literally be anything. So the one you use: `'This thing works'`, seems just fine, although it could be more explicit, for instance: "This user exists". It's unclear, to me, what you mean by: "send back a GET response". What is a "GET response"? The only thing I can think of is that you intent to call an URL with the "token" as a parameter?

Comment: Yes that's it my apologies, I just want the program to register that it is either logged in or not and regularly send a request in the background to a php file to see if the user is still logged in and if the token is still valid

Comment: To be honest, I think I know what you're trying to achieve, but Stack Overflow is for questions about programming problems, not to get a personalized tutorial. I would also like to advice you to pay more attention to what FrankerZ said about the [username and password](https://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) and [binding variables](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-mysql-prepared-statements.php).